# How does the VSC settings for code formatting of TS code and HTML code be shared among different developers?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

How can the VSC settings for code formatting of TS code and HTML code be shared among different developers?

Probably VSC offers a way to export them via a configaration file.

1. How to create/export this file?

And

2. How to apply the settings.json of the folder .vscode automatically in VSC

**Acceptance criteria:**

1) all code formatting rules for TS and HTML are the same between all developers using VSC

2) all code formatting rules for TS and HTML are the same between develoeprs using VSC and Intellij IDEA

3) code formatting rules are automatically applied to VSC (not manually triggered import required)

Comment: store the settings in the Workspace (`.vscode/settings.json`), check in the file in SCM

Comment: I found some solutions related - https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/